# No "Start" menu shortcut using ClickOnce

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I am publishing a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 3.5 SP1 [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application through [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). By default, when the user clicks on the published link the application gets installed and a menu and shortcut are added to the client's Start/All Programs menu.

How can I prevent the shortcut/menu from being created? (Users need to run the application solely by clicking on the hyperlink to the ".application" file on a web page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this behaviour, set it as online only. Project properties -> Publish -> "The application is available online only" (radio button).

It will still do the same local caching of files etc; it is *mainly* the start-menu that changes (I don't have a full list of the differences).

Answer (score 1):

This can also be changed in the .application file by setting `<deployment install="false"`